# I can't do this poof of being even

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I know these things If $x$ is divided by $11$ it remainder of $7$. If $x$ is divided by $13$ it remainder of $7$. If $x$ is divide by $3$ it remainder $3$. $x$ is less than $500$.

I am trying to prove that $x$ even ...

Comment: Do you know the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: If $x$ is divided by $3$ it has a remainder of *what*?

Comment: $3$ so it divides perfectly into it $x$

Comment: I would call that a remainder of $0$

Comment: yes it is $$ $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,x\,$ is a solution so too is $\,x + 3\cdot 11\cdot 13,$ and they have *opposite* parity.

---

Maybe you seek to prove that the *least nonegative* solution is even. Then

coprime $\,11,13\mid x-7\,\Rightarrow\, 11\cdot 13= 143\mid x-7\ $ so $\,x = 7 + 143k$.

Thus ${\rm mod}\ 3\!:\,\ 3 \equiv x \equiv 7+143k\equiv 1+2k\ $ so $\,2k\equiv 2,\,$ so $\,k\equiv 1\ $ so $\, k = 1+3n$

Thus $\,x = 7+143(1+3n) = 150+ 429n$

Comment: what does it mean opposite parity?

Comment: One is odd, the other is even, since adding an odd intger to $x$ changes its parity. So there are both odd and even solutions. So you cannot prove that $x$ is even.

Comment: ok .. so is it $3 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$?? so 429? that isnt even

Comment: I don't really understand why you are multiplying $3,11,13$ anyway

Comment: Because adding that number to $x$ does not affect the remainder $x$ leaves when dividing by $3,11\,$ or $13.\ $ So it is also a solution.  Did you not yet learn the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: ok so whatever x is you can add 429 and that works too and its going to be odd, so i have to check everything 0,2,4,6 up to 71 then it becomes above 500?

Comment: I checked everything up to 70 and nothing works for all three remainder .................................

Comment: I FOUND IT $$x = 150$$ easy after all

Comment: theres a pattern to make it easier to check fast you can skip a lot

Comment: @terrace See my edit. It appears that you omitted a crucial constraint in your question, that you seek the *least nonnegative* solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with modular arithmetic, you can set up your information into modular equivalences:
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv7\mod11\\x\equiv7\mod13\\x\equiv0\mod3\end{cases}$$
You can then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve this. Note that $11,13,3$ are pairwise coprime, and the solution modulo $(3)(13)(11)=429$ is less than $500$. Also note that the last equivalence shows a remainder of $0$ when divided by three, which is equivalent to a remainder of $3$ when divided by $3$ (since the remainder should be less than the divisor).

Comment: I got it its $$x=150$$